# Wildfly 12 - EJB invocations from remote servers under domain controller (Elytron)

Tags: ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.0, wildfly-11, elytron

I am following the instructions from this link: https://developer.jboss.org/people/fjuma/blog/2017/09/08/getting-started-with-ejbs-and-elytron-part-2

Trying to replicate those configurations under domain controller but without success.

I have two server groups, one is client of other. But the servers of server group "B" still unable to lookup the remote EJB from servers of server group "A"

I tried to configure the servers with jboss-cli.sh from domain controller. Applying the configurations at the corresponding profiles.

Ex:

From Domain Controller's jboss-cli.sh:

```
/profile=my-custom-profile-full-ha/subsystem=elytron/authentication-configuration=ejb-auth-config:add(authentication-name=ejb, credential-reference={clear-text="ejbejb"})
```

and so on...
The `socket-binding-group` is defined at domain.xml as well.

But my client server still getting errors when lookup the remote EJB.

Is there other configuration for servers running under domain controller to get remote invocations work?

The error:

```
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: EJBCLIENT000079: Unable to discover destination for request for EJB StatelessEJBLocator for "/portal/SampleEJB", view is interface my.company.ejb.interfaces.SampleEJBRemote, affinity is None
```

Thanks!

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @ValsarajViswanathan nah. i gave up on this. transactional remote call through different server groups seems simply not work, also it is a very bad idea